# implementing custom array adapter for multi dimensional array

Tags: android

So I want to display more than one text view in a list view but I have completely no clue about how to do this. The idea I am trying to implement is actually a list of music files loaded from a multi dimensional array such that

```
String musicFiles[][] = {{"TRACK NAME","ARTIST NAME"}};
```

so that within the same row the array adapter can display the "TRACK NAME" and below that "ARTIST NAME" but obviously the array adapter can not take a multi dimensional array and i have to implement a custom adapter and extend the array adapter class. Problem is I have no idea how to do this. Help!

Comment: where do you keep all of your artists?

Comment: @pskink I serialize the musicFiles string array object to file

Comment: with sqlite and SimpleCursorAdapter you could show your artists in. dozen lines (or so)  of code

Comment: @pskink i want to send this file containing this object to other devices so that the same list on one device can be recreated on other devices without having to send the actual list items...i dont know if am making sense here

Comment: sqlite db is also one file but you can access/update/delete the data far way  easier

Comment: @pskink can a copy of that sqlite db file be sent to another device and accessed?

Comment: this is a normal file, just like data.txt, nothing special

Answer (score 0):

Multidimensional array might not be the simplest solution. I would suggest creating a container class for all required pieces of information about the music file.

Something like this:

```
public class MusicFile {
    public final String trackName;
    public final String artistName;

    public MusicFile(String trackName, artistName) {
        this.trackName = trackName;
        this.artistName = artistName;
    }    
}
```

An then use it inside an array:

```
MusicFile[] music;
```